# Returning a value from a panel in C++?

Tags: event-handling, cursor, c++-cli, mouseevent, clr

Let's say I've the following:

```
private: System::Int64 panel1_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e)
{
    int x; 
    mouse event gives back the value 5.
    x = 5; 
    return x
}
```

How do i call the panel such that it can return 5?? Is there any way possible to do it? Thanks.

P.S: I'm using C++/CLI.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. The function as you wrote it returns 5. This is possible. However, this is a private function, thus you can only call it from member functions.

Comment: hi @tobi303 , can you give me an example on how to return it as a function? I am not sure how to set the arguments if i was to return it as a function.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you mean. Btw, is there any deeper meaning of returning `5`?

Comment: @tobi303 No, there is no other deeper meaning. Its just a simple value of 5. How do i return it?

Comment: As I said, the function in your snippet returns 5 (there is only a small typo: `^` is supposed to be `&`?). I dont know System::Windows etc. but I guess this is the function where you handle the event. Why do you want it to return 5?

Comment: @tobi303 I see, its just a sample value, it can be of any other value, shucks. :/

Comment: You don't "call a panel", the panel calls you.  You can only call code.  And if there is code inside this MouseDown event handler that you want to call from somewhere else then the Smart Thing to do is to move it into a separate method.  So you don't have to fake the MouseEventArgs argument.

Comment: @HansPassant Hi Hans, once again. Unfortunately, that is not the case. In this particular mousedown event, I am able to get the X Y coordinate, but I need to return them so I can call the X and Y somewhere else, any light on this?

Comment: There is no point in "returning" anything, the operating system does not care.  It simply triggered your event handler to let you know that the mouse was clicked, it doesn't expect anything back.  If you want to do something useful with the x,y value you got then you need to pass it to a method that does something useful with it.  Whatever it might be, you consistently avoiding telling us doesn't help us help you.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant Sorry if I sound straightforward but what is that I am avoiding to tell you guys? I mean I am here to seek clarifications and guides to how to solve a particular problem, and I will definitely do all I can to help answer your query so as to be able to solve my problem.

Comment: Just to clarify... Your question looks like your actual problem is not what you are asking for. As mentioned before, this function is indeed returning 5, but your problem is somewhere else. To help with this we need to know more about what you actually want to do, thus 5 is not just "a sample value". Nevermind, hope my answer could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used, System::Windows and the like, and I think your actual problem is some misunderstanding of how to handle the events. However...

"How do i call the panel such that it can return 5??"

From your question I assume that this function is inline in the header of some MyPanel header. I.e. something like:

```
class MyPanel{
    // ... //
    private: 
        System::Int64 panel1_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e)
        {
            int x; 
            //mouse event gives back the value 5.
            x = 5; 
            return x
        }
};
```

This function does return 5 when it is called. However, it is private and can only be called from member functions (or friends).

EDIT: After reading more comments, I think I know what is your problem..
The correct return type of this function is "void" not "int". If you want to process the event further, do it in another function. For example:

```
void myEventHandler(int x){
    std::cout << "Button " << x << " was pressed" << std::endl;
}
void panel1_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e)
{
    myEventHandler(5);
}
```

MouseDown is the function that is called when the mouse is hold down. You dont call it, you just handle your event in it. Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: Hi @tobi303, you got me right there. Yes I'm trying to do something like this, but if you do it that way, wouldn't myEventHandler be in .cpp while the panel1_mousedown be in .h ?

Comment: Sounds like you do not really understand splitting between headers and sources. Try to look for e.g. "definition vs declaration"

Comment: Alright, I understood it. So basically, I cannot return anything in the mousedown, more like I can only execute functions from c.cpp into this mousedown event, right?

Comment: @tobi303 there's no typo here, because it's not C++ but C++/CLI, so `^` is perfectly legit (it's just like `*` actually, only for a managed object). The real problem is that the `MouseDown` event is... well, just an event. It doesn't expect a return value. The expected signature is `void MouseEventHandler(Object^ sender, MouseEventArgs^ e)`

Comment: didnt know, that. When i saw "System::Int64" in the OP, I thought this is the correct signature